# Fill in missing date values within a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe, df, where I would like to fill in missing date values, as well as missing ids.
I also have a few id values that I would like to add into the dataframe, such as 'dd', 'ee' and so on.

**Data**

```
id  date    pwr
aa  Q1.22   10
aa  Q1.22   1
aa  Q2.22   1
aa  Q2.22   5
bb  Q1.22   5
bb  Q1.22   1
bb  Q2.22   1
bb  Q2.22   1
cc  Q1.22   2
cc  Q2.22   2
```

**Desired**

```
id  date    pwr
aa  Q1.22   10
aa  Q1.22   1
aa  Q2.22   1
aa  Q2.22   5
aa  Q3.22   
aa  Q4.22   
bb  Q1.22   5
bb  Q1.22   1
bb  Q2.22   1
bb  Q2.22   1
bb  Q3.22   
bb  Q4.22   
cc  Q1.22   2
cc  Q2.22   2
cc  Q3.22   
cc  Q4.22   
dd  Q1.22   
dd  Q2.22   
dd  Q3.22   
dd  Q4.22
```

**Doing**

I believe I have to establish a range, but not sure how to include the dates if they are quarters.
I am still researching. Any suggestion is appreciated.

```
r = pd.date_range(start=df.dt.min(), end=df.dt.max())
df.set_index('dt').reindex(r).fillna(0.0).rename_axis('dt').reset_index()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the date to a period date type:

```
pat = r"(?P<Q>.)(?P<quarter>\d+)\.(?P<year>.+)"
repl = lambda m: f"{m.group('quarter')}{m.group('Q')}20{m.group('year')}"
df = df.assign(date = df.date
                       .str.replace(pat, repl, regex=True)
                       .transform(pd.Period)
               )

df
 
   id    date  pwr
0  aa  2022Q1   10
1  aa  2022Q1    1
2  aa  2022Q2    1
3  aa  2022Q2    5
4  bb  2022Q1    5
5  bb  2022Q1    1
6  bb  2022Q2    1
7  bb  2022Q2    1
8  cc  2022Q1    2
9  cc  2022Q2    2

df.dtypes
 
id             object
date    period[Q-DEC]
pwr             int64
dtype: object
```

A convenient method to expose the missing values would be to use the [complete](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.complete.html#janitor.complete) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/index.html):

```
# create the period ranges within a dictionary
new_values = {"date" : lambda date: pd.period_range(date.min(), 
                                          periods = 4)}

new_values = [new_values]

# pip install pyjanitor
import janitor
import pandas as pd
df.complete(new_values, by='id')
 
    id    date   pwr
0   aa  2022Q1  10.0
1   aa  2022Q1   1.0
2   aa  2022Q2   1.0
3   aa  2022Q2   5.0
4   aa  2022Q3   NaN
5   aa  2022Q4   NaN
6   bb  2022Q1   5.0
7   bb  2022Q1   1.0
8   bb  2022Q2   1.0
9   bb  2022Q2   1.0
10  bb  2022Q3   NaN
11  bb  2022Q4   NaN
12  cc  2022Q1   2.0
13  cc  2022Q2   2.0
14  cc  2022Q3   NaN
15  cc  2022Q4   NaN
```

Sticking to Pandas only, let's get the unique rows from `df` :

```
temp = df.drop_duplicates(['id', 'date'])
```

The reason for the unique values is so that we can create period ranges per `id` and reindex (reindex does not work with non unique indices):

```
temp = (temp
        .set_index('date')
        .groupby('id')
        .apply(lambda df: df.reindex(pd.period_range(df.index.min(), 
                                                     periods = 4)))
        .drop(columns=['id', 'pwr'])
        )
```

Let's join `temp` back to `df`:

```
In [119]: df.merge(temp, 
                   left_on=['id', 'date'], 
                   right_index = True, 
                   how = 'right')
Out[119]: 
   id    date   pwr
0  aa  2022Q1  10.0
1  aa  2022Q1   1.0
2  aa  2022Q2   1.0
3  aa  2022Q2   5.0
9  aa  2022Q3   NaN
9  aa  2022Q4   NaN
4  bb  2022Q1   5.0
5  bb  2022Q1   1.0
6  bb  2022Q2   1.0
7  bb  2022Q2   1.0
9  bb  2022Q3   NaN
9  bb  2022Q4   NaN
8  cc  2022Q1   2.0
9  cc  2022Q2   2.0
9  cc  2022Q3   NaN
9  cc  2022Q4   NaN
```

Comment: Thank you , I will try. Is there a way to also add the 'dd' (there are a few values that are not in my original dataframe that I would like to add to the new dataframe)

Comment: sorry, I dont get. how do you want to add `dd`?

Comment: comparing dataframe and showing value names that do not match. I have a dataframe that contains aa,bb,cc,dd,ee,ff,gg,hh. I would like to append to the dataframe that only contains aa,bb,cc - The values that do not match will be filled in

Comment: that seems different from the original question posted. you could ask that in a new question, with clear example and you should get some responses

Answer (score 1):

I'd make an extra dataframe with the range and would merge them